# How to execute linux commands from HTML and Javascript pages?

Tags: javascript, html, linux, shell, archlinux

The title says everything..
I would like to execute special shell commands when a specific button is pressed in HTML or Javascript. If possible, can you also give me a test code??

I was wondering if I could make them auto-start in an arch live USB / CD installer and make those HTML pages as some shell command-executor.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can execute linux commands only at backend (php, nodejs, etc).

Comment: Is it only possible like that? Won't HTML's href work?? If only so, is it simple to execute them??    (I'm just learning javascript)

Comment: You can send request from javascript to backend but using html page on "live USB / CD installer" is impossible.

Comment: Why? What happens when an HTML page is executed in a live USB / CD installer?

Comment: @TheBluSalmon, html page can be executed only in browser (which is front-end). You need browser to read/execute html-page.

Comment: Isn't it possible to include the Chromium Web Browser package in arch linux using the "pacman -S chromium" command in autostart, wait for it to download and execute the HTML page?

Comment: @TheBluSalmon, I don't know. Even if you could include it you still can not execute shell commands with front-end javascript.

Comment: Anyways, thanks. I'll go check out backend stuff. Guess I really do have to learn node.js + javascript :I

Comment: @TheBluSalmon, node.js should be installed. I don't know how to install it on "live USB / CD installer" and if it even possible. Most probably the easiest way will be create shell script but it depends on your needs.